# Issues with java-diff-utils when compare text files

Tags: java, diff

I am trying to compare two text files with `java-diff-utils` and I follow this example: https://code.google.com/archive/p/java-diff-utils/wikis/SampleUsage.wiki

But I have discovered sometimes when I have multiple rows in files and differences in several lines, `Patch patch = DiffUtils.diff(originalFile, originalFile)` returns only one change which concatenates all lines in one:

`[ChangeDelta, position: 1, lines: [Line1, Line2] to [Line1*, Line2*]]`

Instead of:

`[ChangeDelta, position: 1, lines: [Line1] to [Line1*]]`

`[ChangeDelta, position: 2, lines: [Line2] to [Line2*]]`

What could be a reason of such behavior?

Answer (score 0):

I think ChangeDelta works at the 'Chunk' level and not the row level. For the row level , they have Class 'DiffRowGenerator'. Here's the link -
http://javadox.com/com.googlecode.java-diff-utils/diffutils/1.2.1/difflib/DiffRowGenerator.html